# How to show Gif in UWP in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, gif

I want to show GIF in my Xamarin forms app. I tried FFImageLoading but it shows GIF in android and iOS but not in UWP. So is there any way I can show GIF in UWP?

Comment: wait until the [PR is merged](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/2202) to have buildin GIF support in XF

Answer (score 0):

> How to show Gif in UWP in Xamarin Forms?

As @agicandre1981 mentioned **Basic GIF animation features** will be merged, you could wait for the following update.

And UWP native image control supports GIF image, So you could use `OnPlatform` xaml tag  to create different image control for per platform like the following.

```
<OnPlatform>
    <On Platform="UWP">
        <Image
    HeightRequest="200"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Source="test.gif"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="200"
    />
    </On>
    <On Platform="Android">
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
    Source = "Test.gif"/>
    </On>
    <On Platform="iOS">
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
    Source = "Test.gif"/>
    </On>
</OnPlatform>
```